# Matching Valid Vlan ID input

Tags: node.js, regex, express-validator, vlan

I am creating an app with NodeJS, which would require users entering valid VLAN ID's. I have successfully created a regex that would match 4 digits, including a comma but no range yet. So far, I have .matches(/^(\d{1,4},)*\d{1,4}$/).withMessage('Invalid Vlans Entered') and this would only check for 4 digits with a comma. I am trying to create a regex that would match just about the main requirements for a valid vlan ID, with the following: 
Not greater than 4094, allowed character should be comma and a hyphen (incase a user specifies a vlan range). I have tried all forms of regex combo, but it doesn't work as expected. Any help at this point would be great. I am using express-validator to validate input.

Comment: @DinethCooray yesss, Thanks a lot, this validation works exactly as needed within my app. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: No problem! glad it helped